# Override less variables in twitter-bootstrap-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-rails

I'm using twitter-bootstrap-rails gem and in `bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less` file I have the next lines:

```
// If you'd like to override bootstrap's own variables, you can do so here as well
// See http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/less.html for their names and documentation
//
// Example:
// @linkColor: #ff0000;
```

But when I uncomment `@linkColor: #ff0000;` I get the following error:

```
Invalid CSS after "...icons-halflings": expected ")", was ".png"");"
```

Am I doing something wrong, or it's the lib's problem?

Answer (score 5):

It seems that removing `.png`s and so changing

```
// Set the correct sprite paths
@iconSpritePath: asset-path('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings.png');
@iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-path('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white.png');
```

into

```
// Set the correct sprite paths
@iconSpritePath: asset-path('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings');
@iconWhiteSpritePath: asset-path('twitter/bootstrap/glyphicons-halflings-white');
```

Solved the problem. I think this is a library error

Comment: Thanks for this solution! I had the same problem and your fix worked.

I made the proposed the edit on Github:
https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails/pull/429

Comment: Thanks! I have a [rails app](https://github.com/toadkicker/teststrap) I am putting together for people using this gem to have an example rails app to view. It's deployed on [heroku](http://teststrap.herokuapp.com/people/). Would love some help throwing some pages together to run tests against.